# localization of a package with gettext/intltool?

Tags: localization, gettext

I am trying to localize my program in linux. The project follows gnu structure(hopefully)

```
$ tree -d
.
|-- autom4te.cache
|-- build-aux
|-- data
|-- help
|   `-- C
|       `-- images
|-- images
|-- m4
|-- po
`-- src
```

Now, I want to localize my package.desktop.in

```
$ cat data/package.desktop.in 
[Desktop Entry]
_Name=package
_GenericName=package
_X-GNOME-FullName= Editor
_Comment=Editor file
_Keywords=Editor
Exec=editor
Icon=editor
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Categories=GNOME;GTK;Utility;
StartupNotify=true
X-GNOME-UsesNotifications=true
```

my help/Makefile.am contains:

```
HELP_LINGUAS = bn_IN
```

Now, I tried to create the .pot file using `gettext` as:

```
po]$ xgettext -o package.pot package.desktop.in
xgettext: warning: file `packege.desktop.in' extension `desktop' is unknown; will try C
xgettext: error while opening "package.desktop.in" for reading: No such file or directory
```

with

```
$ cat POTFILES.in 
data/package.desktop.in
[type: gettext/glade]data/package-menus.ui
data/org.package.gschema.xml.in
```

And my data/ contains:

```
$ tree ../data/*
../data/main-window.ui [error opening dir]
../data/Makefile [error opening dir]
../data/Makefile.am [error opening dir]
../data/Makefile.in [error opening dir]
../data/package.desktop [error opening dir]
../data/package.desktop.in [error opening dir]
../data/package.png [error opening dir]
../data/packege.svg [error opening dir]
../data/org.package.gschema.xml [error opening dir]
../data/org.package.gschema.xml.in [error opening dir]
```

I have also tried intltool, and failed as well.

I was following [this](http://people.gnome.org/~menthos/package-translation-guide-template.html).
Kindly help about this.

Answer (score 0):

although I don't know what an *.in file is, Gettext's `xgettext` tool can only extract strings from a limited set of languages and it's designed to look for specific keywords/functions. (note your error that it will "try C")

You can force a language, e.g. `--language=java` but I think you will be out of luck with your format there.

Your file looks like a language pack as opposed to raw source code, so try renaming it to *.properties and [converting it](http://localise.biz/free/converter/java).

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `intltool-extract` before `xgettext`, like so:

```
# prepare the *.desktop file to be used with intltool-extract
sed -r -e '/^(Name|Comment)\[/d' \
       -e 's/^(Name|Comment)/_\1/' \
       package.desktop > package.desktop.in

# you are missing this step; it creates a *.h file xgettext can parse
intltool-extract --type=gettext/ini package.desktop.in

# then you do
xgettext --keyword=N_:1 --join-existing --output messages.pot package.desktop.in.h

# combine new strings with existing translations
for POFILE in *.po; do msgmerge --update $POFILE messages.pot ; done

# and finally merge back into the desktop file
intltool-merge --desktop-style . package.desktop.in package.desktop
```

Adapted from https://github.com/gottcode/xfce4-whiskermenu-plugin/blob/master/po/update-po.sh